# Paperclip image does not visible when save in aws-sdk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, paperclip

Hi I have included this in my gemfile

```
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.2'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
```

and having these models with association:

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :attachment, as: :attachable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachment
end
```

another model is :

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
  has_attached_file :attach,
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                    :url => ":s3_domain_url",
                    :path => "/contents/:id/:basename.:extension"
  validates_attachment_content_type :attach,
                                    :content_type => ['application/msword',
                                                       'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
                                                       'application/pdf',
                                                       'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png']
end
```

now when I save attachments its present in my database but when I go in my index page and write this

```
<% @departments.each do |department| %>
   <%= image_tag(department.attach.url)%>
<%end%>
```

it gives me error

> undefined method `attach'

Please guide me how to overcome with it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% @departments.each do |department| %>
   <%= image_tag(department.attachment.attach.url)%>
<%end%>
```